# How to make sure the same string doesn't appear next to itself in an array?

Tags: shell-script

I'm making a Rubik's Cube scramble generator, and the turns can't be side by side or else it's useless. I'm trying to stop it from doing the following:
Displaying the same string twice, i.e `R2 R2`
Displaying the same kind of string twice, i.e `R2 R`
Displaying the inverse of the string next to it, i.e `R Ri`

Here's the code:

```
    #!/bin/bash
turns=( R Ri 
    L Li
    U Ui 
    D Di
    F Fi
    B Bi
    R2 L2 
    U2 D2
    F2 B2

)
for ((i=1; i<=$1; i++))
do {
     turnArray[$i]=${turns[$((RANDOM%18))]}
}
done
echo ${turnArray[*]}
```

An example of what I want the result to turn out to be:
Script yields: `D2 B Bi Bi Ri Fi R2 D Li U F2 Ri R2 R2 F2`
*s around what need to be changed: `D2 *B Bi Bi* Ri Fi R2 D Li U F2 Ri *R2 R2* F2`

(In case you're wondering, the lowercase `i` in the turn means "inverted".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

turns=(R Ri L Li U Ui D Di F Fi B Bi R2 L2 U2 D2 F2 B2)

declare -A possible
for i in ${turns[@]}; do
        possible[$i]=$(printf "%s\n" "${turns[@]}" | grep -v ${i:0:1})
done

next=${turns[*]}
for ((i=0; i<$1; i++)); do
        j=$(shuf -n 1 -e $next)
        turnArray[$i]=$j
        next=${possible[$j]}
done

echo ${turnArray[*]}
```

- Precalculate next possible moves in an assoc array `possible`.
- Use `shuf` to choose next move from arguments.